# In militaries, do officers address subordinates as tú or usted?

Tags: ustedeo

I imagine that one would usted anyone outranking them, but does this politeness extend to addressing subordinates?

My instinct as well is that when speaking to someone of the same rank, one might use usted for formal communication and tú for informal.

Does it vary from country to country?

Comment: En los papeles, sí. En la práctica puede variar. Respecto a la policía, muchísimas veces voseo cuando hablo con un policía, y otras tantas más uso el usted. Si la situación es intimidante conviene usar el usted siempre, pero sino yo voseo con todo el mundo. En la Argentina el ustedeo está un poco pasado de moda, aunque se sigue usando en ciertas circunstancias puntuales. Lo que habría que hacer es hablar con un militar y preguntarle *hasta qué punto* usa el ustedeo en la práctica

Answer (score 4):

En España está estipulado en el BOE (Boletín Oficial del Estado).

> Art. 462.
> Todo militar que deba dirigirse de palabra a un superior se cuadrará ante él, saludará y le dirá: «a la orden de (tratamiento) mi (empleo del superior)», cuando tenga tratamiento de Excelencia o Señoría, y «a sus órdenes mi (empleo del superior)» cuando tenga el de **Usted**. En la Armada, cuando corresponda, se dirá «mi comandante», «mi segundo», «mi tercero» o «mi Oficial».

> Art. 491.
> Los Reyes de España tienen el tratamiento de Majestad; el Príncipe de Asturias y los Infantes de España, el de Alteza Real, el Presidente del Gobierno, los Vicepresidentes si los hubiere, el Ministro de Defensa y los Oficiales Generales el de Excelencia; los coroneles y capitanes de navío, el de Señoría, y los restantes miembros de las Fuerzas Armadas, el de **Usted**. Reglamentariamente se determinarán las distintas formas de expresión oral y escrita de estos tratamientos.

<sub>*Fuente [BOE](https://www.boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-1984-12106)*</sub>

Comment: but here the "usted" is referring to the person (of military) reading the instruction, not how they must be addressed by a superior. I do not know what happens in practice, however.

Comment: @Lamak Art. 490 stipulates that "in the military environment, only the treatments indicated in this Title will be used", so the treatments listed in Art 491 must be used by all military personnel. I do not know what happens in practice, however.

Comment: @wimi, yeah, but that Art. is not saying how someone should be addressed by a superior, the "usted" is just the way the "narrator" is speaking to the reader

Comment: @Lamak I do not think "Usted" refers to the reader there. I think "Usted" is a way of addressing, same as "Excelencia" or "Señoría". The articles say that all military personnel who are not "Excelencia" or "Señoría" are to be addressed as "usted".

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. Se pregunta por **cómo se da el tratamiento entre pares**, no por cómo se da el tratamiento hacia un superior. Además, se pregunta por **cómo se da**, distinto de *cómo está estipulado por la ley*. Si la evidencia empírica no lo permite corroborar, de nada sirve saber lo que esté escrito en un papel

Answer (score 3):

The official answer for Spain would be the one provided by [Danielillo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42555/1768). Nevertheless, this is not what happens in day to day life. In informal communication, most officers tend to use *tú* when addressing subordinates. But there are exceptions. For instance, in the Navy it is customary for officers to use *usted* and even *Don* when addressing high ranking NCOs.

I once met a Navy Commander who always addressed his assigned Warrant officer as *Don José*. He explained me that this use was based on the roles in a ship (they were both actually working at the High Command, on land) and many Navy people liked keeping this tradition.

Age also comes into consideration. Usually, young officers don't feel confortable addressing veteran subordinates as *tú* and may resort to *usted*.

In summary: subordinates almost always address their superiors as the ordnance says, but superiors tend to use *tú* when addressing subordinates, with some exceptions.